# Put Seekbar on map view in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to put seek bar over the map view in android.

Any Idea please suggest.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <MapView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can set the *SeekBar* anywhere you want it just set the mapview as `fill_parent` in width and height or you can set the `wrap_content` for don't overlay.

Answer (score 0):

Use Transparent panel to show SeekBar.